# how to catch mongo change streams when one array changes within an object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, changestream

I am trying to setup a change stream filter to detect only when a particular document (_id) has a change within a particular array of key/values. I have the following example mongodb doc, i am trying to detect a change within the 'inventory.0.APPLE' array. note that there is also a duplicate array in the 'inventory.0.DiscountBin.APPLE' which i am not interested in. I've tried the below without any luck.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "64d43991678e200790d54c01"
    },
    "GroceryPlatform": "FruitBasket",
    "StoreName": "Fruit Kingdom",
    "groceryType": "Assorted",
    "storeID": "64d43991678e200790d54c01",
    "inventory": [{
        "Discounts": "Online",
        "Info1": {
            "Layout": "Honeycomb",
            "Lighting": "Grid",
            "Fitout": "Modern Black",
            "Version": "12.2.0"
        },
        "Info3": {
            "Eftpos": {
                "$numberInt": "51"
            },
            "Version": "45.1.11"
        },
        "EnergySaver": "ON",
        "NetworkInfo2": {
            "Hostname": "FruitBasket-010100",
            "IPAddress": "10.10.20.227"
        },
        "APPLE": {
            "Quality": {
                "$numberDouble": "70.868"
            },
            "Weight": {
                "$numberDouble": "0.291"
            },
            "Color": {
                "$numberDouble": "0.78"
            },
            "UsedBy": {
                "$numberDouble": "4.59"
            }
        },
        "Time": "2023-08-20T08:50:27",
        "TotalStock": {
            "$numberInt": "24"
        },
        "AverageCost": {
            "$numberInt": "19"
        },
        "WASTE": {
            "PowerDelta": {
                "$numberInt": "45"
            }
        },
        "DiscountBin": {
            "APPLE": {
                "Quality": {
                    "$numberDouble": "70.868"
                },
                "Weight": {
                    "$numberDouble": "0.291"
                },
                "Color": {
                    "$numberDouble": "0.78"
                },
                "UsedBy": {
                    "$numberDouble": "4.59"
                }
            },
            "Time": "2023-08-20T08:43:39"
        }
    }],
    "__v": {
        "$numberInt": "0"
    }
}
```

```
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        { 'fullDocument._id': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(documentId) },
        { 'updateDescription.updatedFields': { $exists: true } },
        { 'updateDescription.updatedFields.inventory.0.APPLE': { $exists: true } }
      ]
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: The `.0.` here indicating that you're only interested in the change when it is to the first entry in the array?

Comment: Yes, all the entries are contained within this first entry. There is only the .0. Entry in the next inventory array. I want to only be notified of a change to the 'APPLE' array within the .0.

Comment: If I remove all filters except the _id: $match, and  console.log the change it prints out as 'inventory.0.EnergySaver': "ON" or any change to  'inventory.0.'

Comment: Can you add the exact logging statement and the output to the question? What happens if you remove `.0` from the filters? Is there _always_ only a single (maximum) entry in the array? If so I'd suggest changing the schema and not having that field be an array. Would probably simplify things a little bit

Comment: I will post soon, not Infront ATM, this is just an example with bogus data, but the structure is identical. I can't remove the .0. As the data creation is out of my hand, it's automatically generated from an external party. I'm just collecting it and adding it to the inventory field. And individual fields are being added and updated at different times. It's the only way I could get the document to update correctly. Sorry I'm only a newbie to coding in general. I'm sure there is a way, but this is the only structure I have found that works for for updating items within the inventory array.